# Set Connection between two sliders in new version of Swiper Slider

Tags: swiper.js

I have two slider on one page and I want to connect these sliders.

Here you can see how to set connection between two sliders in **OLD** version of Swiper Slider. codepen.io/anon/pen/JKYxKJ?editors=0010

But it doesn't work with new version of Swiper Slider.

Please, help me with it

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there is a change in new version, just replace params with controller and you are good to go. Everything else is the same.